# C++ WinRT - How to dynamically scale WriteableBitmap to match current screen resolution?

Tags: c++, video, uwp, windows-runtime, mode

Let's say you created WriteableBitmap at 1280x720, you wish to match the current screen resolution 1920x1080. How do you scale it ?

Answer (score 0):

just found the solution using ScaleTransform to scale 1280x720 WriteableBitmap to 1920x1080:

```
ScaleTransform m_scale;
Image m_img;
...
m_scale.ScaleX( 1.5 ); // 1280 x 1.5 = 1920
m_scale.ScaleY( 1.5 ); //  720 x 1.5 = 1080
m_img.RenderTransform( m_scale );
...
```

Hopes this help.

Comment: This solution doesn't appear to have anything whatsoever to do with setting the video mode.

Answer (score 0):

You need to rebuild the bitmap and reset it to the Xaml image source.